# Autocad 2016 API: Is it possible to write multiple commands that require addicional inputs?

Tags: c#, autocad

I´m new to this api and I´m trying to give a set of commands that saves the pdf file of the drawing to black and white.. Since the drawing is made of Blocks not made by me and some of them don't change colors just by selecting grayscale.ctb to the style, i was trying to automate a process that i found that works witch is the following commands:

```
acadDoc.SendCommand("CONVERTCTB ");
acadDoc.SendCommand("grayscale.ctb ");
acadDoc.SendCommand("grayscale.stb ");
acadDoc.SendCommand("yes ");
acadDoc.SendCommand("CONVERTPSTYLES ");
acadDoc.SendCommand("grayscale.stb ");
```

If I do this directly in CAD it works fine, but when I run my app, It stops after it runs the first command...

Any ideas as how can I solve this?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to this problem to anyone that might have it.
The way I did it was by creating this method:

```
private static void PressEnterKey(Object o)
    {
        SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}");
    }
```

and then when I send the commands to AutoCad:

```
            Object mxNull = 0;
            _timer = new System.Threading.Timer(PressEnterKey, null, 3000, 0);
            acadDoc.SendCommand("CONVERTCTB grayscale.ctb\ngrayscale.stb\nyes\n");
            _timer = new System.Threading.Timer(PressEnterKey, null, 3000, 0);
            acadDoc.SendCommand("CONVERTPSTYLES grayscale.stb\n ");
```

This just awaits 3 seconds after the command is sent to CAD and then simulates a KeyStroke of {ENTER} to close the warning window.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't test that, but in theory is should work if You write command with all parameters in one string like this:

```
acadDoc.SendCommand("_CIRCLE 0,0 10 ");
```

The next issue is run command in dialogless mode.

I can not test `CONVERTCTB` `CONVERTPSTYLES` on AutoCAD because I'm working on ZWCAD and in ZWCAD both `CONVERTCTB` `CONVERTPSTYLES` cannot run dialogless, maybe AutoCAD can do this.

Default way of run command with no dialog is start it name with `-`.
Like this

```
acadDoc.SendCommand("-CONVERTCTB grayscale.ctb ...");
```

If it fails, You can also try set system variable `FILEDIA` to `0`. this will disable dialogs. After running Your command, be sure You set `FILEDIA` to previous version, if You forget that it may make users nervous :) .

Comment: This is almost correct and I really appreciate you responding to me ;) The command have to be is the same string and followed by "\n" for it to enter. But the dialog is still opening after setting FILEDIA to 0. Is there any other way to bypass that dialog? Thank you so much

Comment: acadDoc.SendCommand("FILEDIA 0\n");
acadDoc.SendCommand("_CONVERTCTB grayscale.ctb\ngrayscale.stb\nyes\n");
acadDoc.SendCommand("FILEDIA 0\n");
acadDoc.SendCommand("_CONVERTPSTYLES grayscale.stb\n ");

Comment: The only this stopping this is the dialog boxes...